# Directional derivatives of collinear vectors

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm currently learning about directional derivative, and I need to figure out something in order to fully understand it: What I understood is that directional derivatives are about infinitesimal changes in **directions**, then we are not really interested in the **magnitude** of that change.

So, can we say that the value of the directional derivative of the vector V and the vector W = 100V (for example) at the point (x,y) are supposed to be almost equal?

Comment: We *are* interested in the magnitude of the change. The directional derivative is the rate of change of the function *in a particular direction* (specified by a unit vector). If you take a function of two variables and think about its graph (a surface in 3-space), then pick a direction in the x-y plane and cut the graph with a vertical plane in that direction, the intersection of the plane and the graph is a planar curve, and then you can pretend that everything happens in that plane and do ordinary one-dimensional calculus there.

Comment: @NickD That deserves to be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @NickD According to the more general definition direction derivative is not necessarly referred to a unit vector. That one is  a more specific definition often used but it in not "the definition". Refer to [Directional Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative)

Comment: @gimusi But if we want to compare directions to find the "best" one (the one pointed by the gradient, actually), we have then to use a unit vector to normalize things by using the same scale, right?

Comment: @RyanB. If the aim is to find the direction of max min variation for the function we can use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}$ for any fixed $|\vec v|=k$ and we don't need $k=1$ (even if often we choose $k=1$). Recall that when the function is differentiable we can use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\nabla f \cdot \vec v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\vec v=(a,b)$ we can define the **directional derivative** as:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+ah,y_0+bh)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$

and if we consider the corresponding unit vector $\hat v=(c,d)$ such that $\vec v = \lambda \hat v$ we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial  \vec v}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda \hat v}=\lim_{h\to 0}\lambda\frac{f(x_0+\lambda ch,y_0+\lambda dh)-f(x_0,y_0)}{\lambda h}=\lambda \frac{\partial f}{\partial \hat v}$$

Answer (score 1):

[ Made my comment an answer at the encouragement of @amd - thanks!]

We *are* interested in the magnitude of the change. The directional derivative is the rate of change of the function *in a particular direction* (specified by a unit vector in that direction). If you take a function of two variables and think about its graph (a surface in 3-space), then pick a direction in the x-y plane and cut the graph with a vertical plane in that direction, the intersection of the plane and the graph is a planar curve, and then you can pretend that everything happens in that plane and do ordinary one-dimensional calculus there.

Comment: I just got it: we are interested in the magnitude of change of the function, but we don't change the magnitude of the directonal vector. This is why we use unit vectors with little, very little magnitude, right?

Comment: We *don't have* to use unit vectors (as @gimusi points out): we don't really care about the magnitude of the vector, just its direction (that's why it's a "directional derivative"). But when unit vectors are available (e.g. in Euclidean spaces), they are convenient. Not sure what you mean by "little, very little magnitude": unit vectors have length 1 by definition.